# returning variable with other functions

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typescript

I have a model...

```
class FormulaModel {
   public productType: string;
   public tone: string;
   public peroxide: string;
   public timing: string;
   public levels: string;
}
```

All but the last properties use a function to return results.

```
        viewModel.stepOne = {
           productType: productTypeResult,
           peroxide: this.peroxide((formulaValue.startingLevel() + 1),(formulaValue.endingLevel() + 1), serviceType.porosity(), serviceType.texture(), productType, serviceType.gray()),
           timing: this.timing(serviceType.gray(), serviceType.texture(), serviceType.porosity(), productType,(formulaValue.endingLevel() + 1)),
           tone: this.tone((formulaValue.endingLevel() + 1),(formulaValue.startingLevel() + 1), serviceType.porosity(), serviceType.texture(), formulaValue.endingTone(), serviceType.gray(), productType),
           levels: this.levelsTones
       };
```

Because the tone function actually calculates both the tone and the levels, I was hoping I could create a variable, levelsTones and while in the tone function assign the values to the levelsTones variable.
Well it doesn't work:-( It does assign the values to the variable but when I go to assign the variable to viewmodel.stepOne I get an error.

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

To make it work I just create a function that returns the assigned variable and it works.

```
public levelsAndTones() {
    return this.levelsTones;
}
```